# How to group count by week date in PowerPivot

Tags: microsoft-excel, powerpivot

I have a table of data in PowerPivot connected to a sharepoint list.  Each row has a date that I need to group by week and count the rows in that week.  Is there a DAX formula or other approach to make this happen?  I have not found a straight forward solution to this issue.  Seems simple enough that there should be a way.

Comment: With regular PivotTable you can group dates by weeks (or months, years or quarters) by: First - Put the date field in the row labels or column labels. Second - open the context menu on one of the dates in the PivotTable using the right mouse button. Third - select "Group..." from the context menu. Fourth - select only "Days" in the "By" field. Fifth - set the number of days to 7. I guess this will work with PowerPivot but don't have time to check just now and won't be online again any time soon.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use the excel WEEKNUM() function in an additional "Weeks" column, then pivot up to the weeks?  If you have a date in cell A2, then in B2 you would have WEEKNUM(A2) to get the weeknumber of the week.  Then pivot on that.