# How do you group by week in Excel PowerPivot?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, powerpivot

Say you have a simple sales table in PowerPivot.  What's the easiest way to allow the data to be grouped by week in a PowerPivot pivot table?

I know excel's basic pivot tables have a group feature, but that doesn't seem to apply with PowerPivot.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/577554/how-to-group-count-by-week-date-in-powerpivot?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common approach I've seen is to use a calendar table. Setting up the calendar table can be a little tricky, but once you have it in the data model, join the calendar table to the sales table on the date. Then you can slice and dice and group by date dimensions such as year, month, week, etc.

Here's a good video that walks you through setting up a basic calendar table. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c4ezRLg31hc

Comment: Please include the relevant parts of the video in the answer in case the link breaks.

Answer (score 0):

```
=[Date]+7-WEEKDAY([Date],2)
```

would be the DAX formula if your week ended on a Sunday